# Find Superior Manager of Given Employee without Connect by Prior clause in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I already written query to find Superior manager of given employee using connect by prior,but I need to avoid Connect by Prior

**Source Table:**

```
Employee_Id Manager Id
1            10
10           20
20           Null
2             5
5             7
7            null
3            6
6           Null
```

**OutPut table**

```
Input          Output
Employee_id    Employee_ID
1              20
2               7
3               6
5               7
```

My Approach:

```
select * from (
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEEs 
START WITH EMPLOYEE_ID = 103
CONNECT BY EMPLOYEE_ID = PRIOR MANAGER_ID
) where manager_id is null
```

**Alternate Approach:**

```
with cte (EMPLOYEE_ID,MANAGER_ID,lev) as (
      select EMPLOYEE_ID, MANAGER_ID, 0 as lev
      from employees
      union all
      select cte.EMPLOYEE_ID, employees.MANAGER_ID, lev + 1
      from cte join
           employees
           on cte.MANAGER_ID = employees.EMPLOYEE_ID

     )
    select * from cte where employee_id=103 and MANAGER_ID is null;
```

but not getting expected output with alternate approach.

Comment: Why do you need to avoid connect by prior?

Comment: this was asked in my interview, and they asked me to write the query without using connect by prior.

Comment: "superior manager" is the manager of the manager of the employee?

Comment: yeah but it should check till last level and return  manager id where mgr_id is null. e.g. for employee_id=2, employee_id=7 is the ultimate superior manger.

Comment: @Ganesh perhaps they were expecting you to use [recursive subquery factoring](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/recursive-subquery-factoring-11gr2) instead?

Comment: i used recursive query using WITH clause, but i am not getting expected results. I mentioned my query in the Post itself

Comment: In your expected results, why is the row for employee_id = 10 not there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your recursive subquery factoring, you need to identify the root employee_id and use that in your final query, like so:

```
WITH your_table AS
 (SELECT 1 employee_id, 10 manager_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 10 employee_id, 20 manager_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 20 employee_id, NULL manager_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 employee_id, 5 manager_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 employee_id, 7 manager_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 7 employee_id, NULL manager_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 employee_id, 6 manager_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 employee_id, NULL manager_id FROM dual),
recursive(employee_id,
          manager_id,
          root_emp_id) AS
 (SELECT employee_id,
         manager_id,
         employee_id root_emp_id
  FROM   your_table
  WHERE  manager_id IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT yt.employee_id,
         yt.manager_id,
         r.root_emp_id
  FROM   recursive r
  INNER  JOIN your_table yt
  ON     r.manager_id = yt.employee_id)
SELECT root_emp_id employee_id,
       employee_id ultimate_manager_id
FROM   recursive
WHERE  manager_id IS NULL
ORDER BY employee_id;

EMPLOYEE_ID ULTIMATE_MANAGER_ID
----------- -------------------
          1                  20
          2                   7
          3                   6
          5                   7
         10                  20
```

This mimics the connect_by_root function in connect by hierarchical queries.